# In NLP/probability/ML notation: what does a tilde over a letter mean?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, nlp

I am reading [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/juxddtvfvlf51yv/paper/convex.pdf) paper. In section 1.1 he says:

[image]

What do the tildes above the letters mean? How can I translate this sentence into ordinary English?

Comment: It means empirical distribution from the data you observe, as opposed to model distribution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically two objects which you have to understand

- `P(.)`  (notation without tilde) refer to the actual, true, **unknown** distribution of data/labels/features/other things. We assume that such objects exists and we are trying to somehow estimate it
- `~P(.)` (notation with tilde) usually refers to some kind **estimation** of `P(.)` (or at least an object which is **proportional** to P(.)). In most cases it is some simple empirical estimator, like fraction of things passing the predicate to all "things". However, it can get arbitrary complex (like Kneser-Nay estimation of language model with markov property)

So the translation would be:

- `P(.)` -> probablity of ...
- `~P(.)` -> estimation of the probablity of ...

Comment: What do you mean by the estimation ~P(.) is at least proportional to the probability P(.)? The true distribution should sum to 1 for all sentences in a language. So should the estimation since it is also a probability distribution. To functions f and g are proportional if there is a constant a such that f = ag. In the case of the estimation this can't be true.

Comment: I mean, that sometimes it is not a true estimation but also **unnormalized** estimation (which does not sum to 1), like count of word is an unnormzlied estimation of the probability of observing a word. It is sometimes used in ML in models where calculation of denominator is too expensive, like CRF or DBM

Answer (score 2):

In the quote, P-tilde denotes the empirical distribution. However, the usual symbol for empirical distribution is P-hat -- by extension of the use of `^` to mark estimates. P-tilde is often used to denote an unnormalized distribution: a measure that is intended to be a probability but does not sum/integrate to 1, so it needs to be normalized to be a proper probability distribution.